# Angular: ng test runs but doesnt execute test cases

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular6

I get the below messages after executing command `ng test`. It runs with out any errors but doesn't execute test cases. Any idea why it's not executing the tests?

My project is upgraded from Angular 2 to 4, 5 & now 6. Is it because the karma library has not upgraded properly?

I have created new Angular 6 project and tried `ng test` it works there but doesn't work on my project. I have deleted the `node_modules` folder and installed it by `npm install`, but it is still not working. Any other sugessions?

```bash
10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active(node:9836) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on  .hooks instead
28 06 2018 11:23:24.302:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
28 06 2018 11:23:24.399:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
28 06 2018 11:23:24.402:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
28 06 2018 11:23:24.426:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome 95% emitting CopyPlugi
28 06 2018 11:24:31.561:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
28 06 2018 11:24:42.702:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
28 06 2018 11:24:43.272:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
28 06 2018 11:24:48.951:INFO [Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket VC2A92U8dwahjxB5AAAA with id 78549298
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 41 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
28 06 2018 11:25:16.507:WARN [Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 41 DISCONNECTED (10.004 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 41 DISCONNECTED (10.004 secs / 0 secs)
```

I got this working by removing ngx-translation import. But its not fix as with out importing translation I wont be able to proceed further.

Anyone implemented the ngx-translation in Unit test cases.

Comment: Try opening a browser to http://localhost:9876/ after you run `ng test` and see if that works. The output above indicates it has no captured browser to run the tests in. If that doesn't work, can you provide some working code so others can debug?

Comment: It actually opens browser and prints Security in it and doesnt execute test cases. Do you any idea like why it prints Security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when jasmine goes in to a loop. Actually because of my translate service, It was going in the loop and which was causing karma not to run any test cases and exit, giving error 0 of 43 test executed.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the information: 
To find the exact issue about this, run the test case with -sm=false.

```
C:\Angular>ng test -sm=false
```

I was stuck in this for a while. Above command gave me the exact issue needs to be resolved. Hope it will be helpful to others getting this issue.